# How to find circular dependency of a string using Java

Tags: java

If I have 2 files say ABCD.txt and DEF.txt. I need to check if the String "ABCD" is present in DEF.txt and also the string "DEF" present in ABCD.txt and write the combination to a file.

Totally I have around 15000 files and each file contain nearly 50 - 3000 lines has to be searched. I wrote a piece of code, its working.. but it takes one hour to display the entire list...

Is any better way of performing this? Please suggest me.

```
   public void findCyclicDependency(){

    Hashtable<String, String> htFileNameList_1  = new Hashtable<String, String>();  
    Hashtable<String, String> htCyclicNameList  = new Hashtable<String, String>(); 

    FileWriter fwCyclicDepen = null;
    PrintWriter outFile = null;

    FileInputStream fstream = null;     
    FileInputStream fstream_1 = null; 

    DataInputStream in = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    DataInputStream in_1 = null;
    BufferedReader br_1 = null;

    String strSV_File_CK="";  

    boolean bFound = false;
    File fileToSearch = null;

    String strSVFileNameForComparison = "";
    String strSVDependencyFileLine = "";
    String strSVDFileLineExisting = "";
    String strCyclicDependencyOut = "";

    try {            
        File baseInputDirectory = new File(strInputPath);            

        List<File> baseInputDirListing = FileListing.getFileListing(baseInputDirectory);

        // Printing out the filenames for the SodaSystem
        for (File swPackage : baseInputDirListing) 
        {

            if (swPackage.isDirectory() && swPackage.getName().endsWith("Plus")) {
                List<File> currSwPackageFileListing = FileListing.getFileListing(swPackage);
                System.out.println("\n swPackage File --> " + swPackage.getName() );
                strCyclicDependencyOut = strOutputPath + "_"+ swPackage.getName() + "_CyclicDependency.xml";
        System.out.println("\n strCyclicDependencyOut File --> " + strCyclicDependencyOut );
        fwCyclicDepen = new FileWriter(strCyclicDependencyOut);
        outFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(fwCyclicDepen));
        outFile.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        outFile.write("<CyclicDependencyFile>");

                 for (File DependentFile : currSwPackageFileListing) {                        
                    strSV_File_CK = DependentFile.getName().substring(0, (DependentFile.getName().length() - 4)).trim();

                    htFileNameList_1.put(strSV_File_CK.toUpperCase(),strSV_File_CK.toUpperCase());
                 }


                for (File DependentFile : currSwPackageFileListing) 
                {                        
                    fstream = new FileInputStream(DependentFile);
                    // Get the object of DataInputStream
                    in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                    strSVFileNameForComparison = DependentFile.getName().substring(0, (DependentFile.getName().length() - 4)).trim();

                    //Read File Line By Line
                    while ((strSVDependencyFileLine = br.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        bFound = false;                                            

                        if (strSVDependencyFileLine.toUpperCase().indexOf("INDICES") == -1) 
                        {
                            //Check the current line matches any of the file name in software package folder
                            if (htFileNameList_1.contains(strSVDependencyFileLine.trim().toUpperCase())
                             && strSVDependencyFileLine.compareTo(strSVFileNameForComparison) != 0)
                            {  
                              bFound = true;

                              // Get the file to search
                              for (File searchFile : currSwPackageFileListing) 
                              {

                                  if((searchFile.getName().substring(0, (searchFile.getName().length() - 4)).trim()).equals(strSVDependencyFileLine))
                                  {
                                      fileToSearch = searchFile;
                                      break;
                                  }
                              }

                              // Read the file where the file name is found
                              fstream_1 = new FileInputStream(fileToSearch);

                              in_1 = new DataInputStream(fstream_1);
                              br_1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in_1));

                              while ((strSVDFileLineExisting = br_1.readLine()) != null)
                              {
                                  if (strSVDFileLineExisting.toUpperCase().indexOf("EXTRA") == -1) 
                                    {
                                        if (htFileNameList_1.contains(strSVDFileLineExisting.trim().toUpperCase()) && bFound 
                                                && strSVDFileLineExisting.compareTo(strSVDependencyFileLine) != 0 
                                                && strSVDFileLineExisting.compareTo(strSVFileNameForComparison) == 0 )
                                        {

                                            if(!htCyclicNameList.containsKey(strSVDependencyFileLine) && 
                                                    !htCyclicNameList.containsValue(strSVDFileLineExisting))
                                              {
                                                htCyclicNameList.put(strSVDFileLineExisting,strSVDependencyFileLine);

                                                outFile.write("<CyclicDepedency FileName = \"" +  strSVDFileLineExisting + "\""+ " CyclicFileName = \"" + 
                                                    strSVDependencyFileLine + "\" />");
                                                    break;
                                              }

                                        }
                                    }

                              }

                            }         

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            bFound = false;
                        }                               

                        }//if current line <> 

                    }// reach each line in the current file

                outFile.write("</CyclicDependencyFile>");
            } 
            outFile.flush();
            outFile.close();

        }         

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks
Ramm

Comment: It would be vital to copy here a code fragment, which is cleaned up from other specific parts and concentrates only for the pure problem itself. Current code has too many responsibilities. It's hard to tell what's the real reason of the slowness.

Comment: @pcjuzer: I copied entire code to make sure what I coded is correct. Pls forgive me if it confused you. Actually I am reading each file inside a folder and checking each line inside a file. if the file line is a file, then I will navigate to that file and check for the line of the first file, if it exists.. then I am writing them to an XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your design. The most important one is repeated scanning of the file system. Try the code below.

```
static public void findCyclicDependency2() {
    PrintWriter outFile = null;

    Map<String,File> fileNames = new HashMap<String,File>();
    Map<String,Set<String>> fileBackward = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
    Map<String,Set<String>> fileForward = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();

    try {
        File baseInputDirectory = new File(strInputPath);

        List<File> baseInputDirListing = getFileListing(baseInputDirectory);

        // Printing out the filenames for the SodaSystem
        for(File swPackage:baseInputDirListing) {

            if (! (swPackage.isDirectory()
                    || swPackage.getName().endsWith("Plus"))) continue;

            System.out.println("Loading file names");
            List<File> currSwPackageFileListing = getFileListing(swPackage);
            for(File dependentFile:currSwPackageFileListing) {
                String name = trimName(dependentFile);
                fileNames.put(name,dependentFile);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dependentFile));
                String line;
                Set<String> contFor = new HashSet<String>();
                Set<String> contBack = new HashSet<String>();
                while( (line=br.readLine()) != null ) {
                    line = line.toUpperCase().trim();
                    if( line.equals("EXTRA") ) continue;
                    if( line.equals("INDICES") ) continue;
                    if( line.equals(name) ) continue;

                    if( line.compareTo(name) == 1 ) {
                        contFor.add(line);
                    } else {
                        contBack.add(line);
                    }
                }
                fileBackward.put(name,contBack);
                fileForward.put(name,contFor);
            }

            String strCyclicDependencyOut = strOutputPath + "_"
                    + swPackage.getName() + "_CyclicDependency.xml";
            outFile = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(strCyclicDependencyOut)));
            outFile.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            outFile.write("<CyclicDependencyFile>");

            for(Entry<String,Set<String>> entry : fileForward.entrySet()) {
                String curr = entry.getKey();
                for(String other : entry.getValue()) {
                    Set<String> otherRefs = fileBackward.get(other);
                    if( otherRefs == null ) continue;
                    if( otherRefs.contains(curr) ) {
                        outFile.write("<CyclicDepedency FileName = \""
                                + fileNames.get(curr).getPath()
                                + "\""
                                + " CyclicFileName = \""
                                + fileNames.get(other).getPath()
                                + "\" />");
                    }
                }
            }


            outFile.write("</CyclicDependencyFile>");
            outFile.flush();
            outFile.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for the updated code. But at this line "if( otherRefs.contains(curr)".. java.lang.NullPointerException is seen... and "otherRefs" value is printing null .

Comment: That would be because the line in the current file does not refer to an existing file. I have added a null check between getting the set and using it to handle that case.

Comment: I added that code, when I found null value returned. But somehow, the control is not entering into if( otherRefs.contains(curr) ).. so the output file has no lines except header part. the value in the "OtherRefs" is null all the time.Thanks

Comment: how did you implement `trimName(File)` ? I should have given you the implementation which is `private static String trimName(File f) { String n=f.getName(); return n.substring(0,n.length()-4).trim().toUpperCase(); }` Without the toUpperCase the names will not match in case.

Answer (score 1):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) comes to my mind.

Maybe it's more efficient to index all files, then query for the file names and use the results to detect your circular dependencies.

Comment: Lucene might be a good idea, however only so if the corpus of files is static and does not change often. Otherwise you will just loose the time you saved while searching on creating the Lucene index.

Comment: The full index should be created in less then 3 minutes. Then we have 57 minutes left for the cycle detection ;)